# Create a value using MAX with a range that is dependent on the value of an adjacent column

Tags: excel, vba

I have three columns. The first column is a ranked column 1-67 with hundreds of entries receiving a 1 and the same for the rest. The second column is the "data". In the third column i need the MAX value (from the data in column 2 to match up with the RANKING so the value of all the 1s would be displayed in the third column as the highest 1 value in column 2)

```
A  B  C
1 235 235
1 234 235
1 231 235
2 233 245
2 245 245
3 221 241
3 234 241
3 241 241
3 201 241
```

Comment: have a look in [**`here`**](http://superuser.com/questions/637303/excel-find-indices-of-value-in-list-then-return-largest-index-value-from-other/637307#637307) that may help you get started

Comment: @mehow that doesn't quite work. I know it will involve an array but there is not a defined number of cells that would go into each range. There will wind up being over 10000 rankings/groups with a varying number of cells that max would need a range for to compute anything.

Comment: and how was I supposed to know that? I dont have time for guessing what ur problem is.

Comment: Sorry for the incomplete information I do apologize. I added a more visual example of what I am trying to accomplish in the C column.

Comment: ok so using the basic jist of the link above that you provided when you create the array down the page is there a way to make the C1 dymanic in the fomula so it changes in every place of the array?=MAX(IF(A1:A12=OFFSET(C1,0,-2), B1:B12))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution is to use nested functions.

Assuming your data starts in row 1, you can write the following formula in cell C1:

```
=MAX(IF(A:A=A1,B:B,""))
```

(I'm assuming that the columns in the whole worksheet are relevat to your problem)

Be sure to press `[Ctrl]+[Shitf]+[Enter]` to make this a "matrix function".

---

Another possible solution is to create a pivot table, and use `GetPivotData()` to get the max value:

1. Put headers to your table
2. Create a pivot table
3. Put the "rank" column in the "row header" area
4. Put the "data" column in the "value" area. Right click it, and select Summarize Data > Max
5. In your table, write this formula: `=GetPivotData("Max Of Data",SheetX!A1,"rank",A2)`

(I am assuming that the pivot table is created in the cell `A1` of the sheet `SheetX`

Comment: the first solution that you offer is only giving me one output for the C column which is the highest for the entirety the B column. It is not segmenting the highest per rank

Comment: @user2726089 are you sure you pressed [Ctrl]+[Shift]+[Enter] when you entered the formula? (if you select the cell, the formula should appear enclosed in curly brackets: `{=MAX(IF(A:A=A1,B:B,""))}`

Comment: I was using it as a matrix but I had highlighted the entire C column instead of just the C1 cell before doing ctrl shift enter and then dragging down, also it looks like I had calculation options set to not automatic which may have had something to do with it. Seems to be working now on my small data set I will give it a go on the 1,000,000 plus entries that it is needed for. THANKS

Comment: @user2726089 If your dataset is so large, you should really consider the pivot table option, or (better) use a database. Anyway, happy to help